# arm-none-eabi-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, mingw, createprocess

I have a problem with arm-none-eabi-g++ compiler running on Windows.
When I run my makefile on Ubuntu, everything works fine.

Makefile target fails on Windows with error

```sh
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

I'm using MingGW on Windows. MinGW, make and G++ locations are added to Win PATH.

Compiler and make are the same versions on both OS.

## Ubuntu

```sh
getconf ARG_MAX
2097152

arm-none-eabi-g++ --version
arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 7-2018-q3-update) 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907]
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

## Windows 10 with MinGW

```sh
getconf ARG_MAX
32000

arm-none-eabi-g++ --version
arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 7-2018-q2-update) 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907]
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for i686-w64-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

## More information

This is how one of my makefile targets look like

```
$(PROJECT).o: $(PROJECT).cpp
    @echo start of $(@F)
    $(CPP) $(CC_FLAGS) @./.symbols.txt -std=gnu++11 -fno-rtti @./.includes.txt -o $@ $<
    @echo end of $(@F)
```

Interesting thing is, that Windows build works fine only if the size of .symbols.txt and .includes.txt combined is lower than 32k. So it might look like it depends on ARG_MAX size (which is on MINGW 32k), but it's probably not true. Because another target in the same makefile looks like

```
$(PROJECT).elf: $(SYS_OBJECTS)
    $(file > .sys_objects.txt, $(SYS_OBJECTS))
    $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) -o $@ @./.sys_objects.txt $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS) $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS)
```

and it works well on Windows despite that sys_objects.txt size is about 90k.

Both $(LD) and variables $(CPP) variables are set to arm-none-eabi-g++.

Another thing I have noticed is that something on Windows adds a file like C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQWU5K6.s to the end of g++ command (regardless if it fails or not). I have no clue where does this come from (maybe some MINGW support argument?).

Has anyone a clue why build fails on Windows with arguments bigger than 32k even if another target works fine with big arguments? Maybe it might be a coincidence.

Comment: Looks like this problem was caused by using 7.3.1 20180622. Now I have tried gcc version 9.2.1 20191025 and everything works fine.